When loading my userform i get Run-Time Error 381: Could not set the list property. Invalid property array index
When loading my userform in word i get Run-time error 381: Could not set the list property. Invalid Property array index. The aim is to generate a userform with a dependent combobox (Attention) and independent combobox (CompanyName) grabbing info from a separate excel spreadsheet
I don't know whats wrong with my code and how to fix it.

Option Explicit
Private oVars As Variables
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim c As Excel.Range
Dim arrData As Variant


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Call LoadData
Dim arr(), i As Long
ReDim arr(1 To UBound(arrData) - 1)
For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
    arr(i - 1) = arrData(i, 1)
Next
Me.CompanyName.List = arr

Caption = "Fill Me Out Please"
Label1.Caption = "Company Name"
Label2.Caption = "Attention of"
Label3.Caption = "Signature"
Label4.Caption = "Drawings"
Label5.Caption = "Calculation"
Label6.Caption = "Design Criteria Number"
Label7.Caption = "Rev"
Label8.Caption = "Rev"
Label9.Caption = "Design Criteria Dotpoints"
Label10.Caption = "Exclusions"

CommandButton1.Caption = "OK"
CommandButton2.Caption = "Cancel"
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("FileName.xlsx")
CompanyName.List = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A29").Value
SigName.List = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A29")

xlBook.Close savechanges:=True
xlApp.Quit

End Sub


Sub LoadData()

Dim isNewApp As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    isNewApp = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("FileName.xlsx")
arrData = xlBook.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Value
xlBook.Close False
If isNewApp Then xlApp.Quit

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
    
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("FileName.xlsx")
Set c = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:=Me.CompanyName.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    oVars("CompanyName").Value = c
    c = c.Offset(0, 1)
    oVars("Address").Value = c
    c = c.Offset(0, 2)
    oVars("Suburb").Value = c
    c = c.Offset(0, 3)
    oVars("State").Value = c
    c = c.Offset(0, 4)
    oVars("PostCode").Value = c
    c = Me.CompanyName.Value
End If

Set c = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells.Find(what:=Me.Sig.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    oVars("SigName").Value = c
    c = c.Offset(0, 1)
    oVars("Position").Value = c
    c = c.Offset(0, 2)
    oVars("Qualification").Value = c
    c = Me.CompanyName.Value
End If

xlBook.Close savechanges:=True
xlApp.Quit
    
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
Set oVars = Nothing
Unload Me

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'User has cancelled so unload the form
Unload Me

End Sub


Private Sub CompanyName_Change()

Me.Attention.Clear
Dim sCom As String: sCom = Me.CompanyName.Value
Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, arr()
ReDim arr(1 To UBound(arrData, 2) - 1)
For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
    If sCom = arrData(i, 1) Then
        For j = 2 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            If Len(arrData(i, j)) = 0 Then
                Exit For
            Else
                r = r + 1
                arr(r) = arrData(i, j)
            End If
        Next
        If r > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(1 To r)
            Me.Attention.List = arr
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub



Here SigName.List = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A29") missing the .Value property
